# after install SSL, it shows your site is not fully secured

Tags: ssl

I recently installed ssl certficate on my doamin. Everything worked fine except for two problems

1 - my domain shows like this in the address bar :  https://www.creativecube.io//

```
how do i set it up so it always shows as https://www.creativecube.io
```

2 - when the site loads it says secure but then by the time the site is fully loaded it turns into the "i" symbol and reads 
your site is not fully secured. I have narrowed it down to this line in the code:

```
<body class="is-disable-scroll" data-lang="en" data-base="" data-json="global.json">
```

what can i do to fix these issues?

Comment: 2) Look in the error console, you are using a resource that is not also served over HTTPS: *Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.creativecube.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://veille.reputationsquad.com//datas//media//reputationsquad-team-veille.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.*

Comment: 1) Google for your webserver name, e.g. *apache always redirect to https*